# How to create black and white 1 bit per pixel bitmap from component and print it to zebra printer?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, zebra-printers, zpl

I am writing simple application to print label with Zebra programming language ZPL and Flex. At current stage i want to print graphics and text as graphic. So the steps i need to perform is:

1. Capture BitmapData (black and white 1 bit per pixel) from spark
   component like Label, for example. I think that i have to use `BitmapData.draw`
   function, but i dont know how to make it black and white and 1 bit
   per pixel;
2. Represent data in ASCII hexadecimal string.( For example 32x32 px
   black rectangle will look like this
   `~DG000.GRF,00512,008,
   ,:::::::::::H07FLF80,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::,:::::::::::::::::::`
   **part of label design, exported by official Zebra Designer label editor*)

   where
    *~DG* - Command to download graphic;
   *000.GRF* - File Name and extension;
   *00512* - total number of bytes in graphic;
   *008* - number of bytes per row;
   *rest* - is The data string defines the image and is an ASCII hexadecimal representation of the image. Each character represents a horizontal nibble of four dots.

I found an answer to step 2 using C# in following post - 
[How to generate a dynamic GRF image to ZPL ZEBRA print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054626/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-grf-image-to-zpl-zebra-print)
I need about the same but written in ActionScript.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to make a `BitmapData` be 1 bit per pixel, instead you query it pixel by pixel by using `getPixel()` and check if it's dark enough to be called "black", if yes, act as if this "bit" is 0.

Comment: I thing it is good idea to get value of red channel of pixel **(value >> 16) & 0xFF** and if it's less then 128, then "1" otherwise "0". Thank You.