# How to reference the Paint.NET assemblies directly using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dll-reference, paint.net

I wanted to reference the Paint.NET assemblies directly and use a its functionality that way. i dont know how to use the .dll file **PaintDotNet.Core.dll**
and use it functionality in C# visual studio any helps. Please

**want to reference to these assemblies: C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\PaintDotNet.*.dll Then poke around the classes in those namespaces.**

Codes:-

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    string filename = "";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
    }
   // MessageBox.Show(filename, "file");
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = filename;
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to continue?", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\PaintDotNet.exe");
       // here i need to perform the function like
       //Open + O`
       //ctrl + Shift + L)` then `
       //(ctrl + Shift + G)`. then save 
       //`ctrl + Shift + S`
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to use the reference. Have you tried referencing it in your Visual Studio Solution->Project? If you want to automate the program, you could try loading the program inside yours with Assembly.Load() and then running the entry point of the MainModule. I don't know anything about Paint.NET though.

Comment: As far as I know, paintdotnet doesn't have an API which is meant for external use. They only offer development of plugins which work within the scope of the main paintdotnet application.

Comment: For such macros (sequence of keys to make some automatic operation) you do not need C#. Just use some dedicated tool like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

Comment: @KonradKokosa ok i saw this.. but how can i open image using these.. convert to bmp file using this autohotkey

Comment: @KonradKokosa actually i checked the autohotkey.. we need to press any key to activate this right.. where i don't like to press any key.. the moment it get activated.. it should start doing.. seems crazy rite.. i know.. but i need in this way..

Comment: I don't think that dll gives any kind of feature to call the function from outside the application. if you are trying to fire the Open File Or Save file event from outside the application then I don't think that is possible. yeah, but you can send any shortcut keys to another application by making that application at foreground and send the shortcut key sequence by using `Send.SendWait()` method. You can read this post for more information http://stackoverflow.com/a/15292428/3761928

Comment: @Shell yes excatly shell. I need to run the apalication. then i need to send these key..  //Open + O`
       //ctrl + Shift + L)` then `
       //(ctrl + Shift + G)`. then save 
       //`ctrl + Shift + S`.. This was the one i was looking for.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the instruction to send the shortcut key to another application

Add this namespace to the class

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then declare `SetForegroundWindow` function with `DllImport` statement. this will create object of that method which has been created in `User32.dll`

```
[DllImport ("User32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);
```

And add the following code to your button click or anywhere in your project. This code will navigate the `OpenFileDialog` to open the existing file in `Paint.NET` application.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("PaintDotNet").FirstOrDefault();
    if (p != null)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle); //Set the Paint.NET application at front
        SendKeys.SendWait("^(o)"); //^(o) will sends the Ctrl+O key to the application. 
    }
}
```

most of programmers made the mistake between `Ctrl+O` and `Ctrl+o` seems similar but, the ascii value of both key is different. So, make sure the key character is not in uppercase. You can also read the full information about `SendKey` method on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx). You can make any key combination and send through the `SendWait()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one or some or all of the libraries to your project. as Measuring states then use the object explorer.

NOTE: never mind the .xaml stuff or the actual projects I am trying to render SharpDX D3D11 in a wpf app to make a map editor (and without the toolkit (don't ask me why. I am crazy)).

I swear I have the code last night are you trying to automate paint.net?
you will have to make a plug-in which would make the process way more streamlined than having to start a second app.

[image: vs2012 screen shot]

Comment: i already added the references.. tell me how to activate.. these functions of .net paint.. nobody is telling that :-(

Comment: after opening the paint i need to do these functions.. thats it.. //Open + O`
       `//ctrl + Shift + L)` then `
       `//(ctrl + Shift + G)`. then save 
       `//`ctrl + Shift + S`.. save as.. .`pcx file type.. :-)

Comment: well I doubt you will find the proper documentation. but you can guess the rest of your life away. after you reference a library to your project place `using somenamespace` namespaces are listed under where you see PaintDotNet.Base. now try and instantiate whatever you can get your hands on. now realize that you are barking up the wrong tree. what you really want to do is emulate a keyboard that sends commands to whatever has focus. but maybe it would first check to see if paintdotnet has focus. if true. the keyboard emulator just sends the OS input. as Konrad said in your question comments 12

Comment: can  you help me automatically convert a .png file to .GRF file.. that's all i need.. can you help programatically.. please

Comment: do you have a link to the specification for a GRF file. frankly I have not heard of that. but PNG are easily loaded into memory Via a call to `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D.FromFile`.

Comment: @StacyKebler is this the GRF you are talking about? [GRAPH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphEdit)

Comment: hehehe..... yes.. i will show you.. its like.. lets say.. i draw a line in a paint... then.. if i convert to grf it looks like.. https://imageshack.com/i/f0sKfg2Rp the black part looks with letter F rest every thing.. white will be zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62789/discussion-between-stacy-kebler-and-radiospace).

Comment: @StacyKebler have you seen this? [zebra question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054626/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-grf-image-to-zpl-zebra-print)